# How to read @key from the JSON object using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this json object:

```
[{"@type":"XPickup","companyId":24,"companyCode":null}]
```

How do I read @type in my angularjs controller to display or modify it. I am unable to access it using:

```
$scope.object.@type // syntax error
$scope.object.type // undefined
```

> Please tell me how do I access the @type key from my json object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$scope.load.loadStops[0]['@type']` or
`$scope.load.loadStops[0]["@type"]`

Comment: $scope.load.loadStops[0].["@type"] gives me syntax error

Comment: '@type'  ie. (with single quotes) will not give you the error if it is sharing your code.

Comment: eclipse highlights the line to have errors with this:

console.log($scope.load.loadStops[0].['@type']);

Answer (score 0):

It will not work.. because @ is giving issue, remove @ then it will work..

```
$scope.data= [{"type":"XPickup","companyId":24,"companyCode":null}];
$scope.newData= $scope.data[0];
```

`$scope.newData.type` will access value

Comment: gives me syntax error:

$scope.newData = $scope.load.loadStops[0];
                  $scope.newData.@type;

Comment: Actually I am getting @type from this json object:

$scope.load; then $scope.load.loadStops; then $scope.load.loadStops[0].@type